# Elements aren't appending correctly to div box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get my div box contents to append into the empty box an revert back into my sortable. Seems simple enough, hopefully one can see what I cannot. Code is here --> http://jsfiddle.net/Awh3G/61/

Later on down the line, I want to implement a loading scroll. If there are ideas, I'm open to hear them

Comment: Please post your code *in* your question; not just a link to your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: My apologies, the code in question is $('li').draggable({revert:true, start: function() { 
    contents = $(this).text();
    }
    });
    $('#drop').droppable({hoverClass:'border',
drop: function (){
$('#drop').append(contents + '<br/>');
    }
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your li's all have the same ID. that is invalid.

in order to have the sortable revert, you use the option for reverting.

And in order to append the value, you use the ui variable they give you.

Read this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop

After you read that, you can see it implimented here:
http://jsfiddle.net/lathan/Awh3G/62/`

```
$('.sorting').sortable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    scroll: false,
    revert: true
});


$('#dropin').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(e,ui) {
        $('#dropin').append(ui.draggable.html() + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me. I'm still a novice at coding and I'm just trying to be great. I really really appreciate the help